# Connecting to Could SQL from local machine via proxy

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am following these instructions to deploy a Django app on Google App Engine:
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

I have got as far as downloading the proxy .exe file (I am on a Windows machine) and connecting to it:

> 2019/01/08 16:14:08 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for
>   [INSTANCE-NAME] 2019/01/08 16:14:08
>   Ready for new connections

When I try and create the Django migrations by running `python manage.py createmigrations` I see the connection received by the proxy file:

> 2019/01/08 16:15:06 New connection for
>   "[INSTANCE-NAME]"

However, after a couple of seconds pause I get this error:

> 2019/01/08 16:15:28 couldn't connect to
>   "[INSTANCE-NAME]": dial tcp
>   35.205.185.133:3307: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I have tried disabling my local firewall in case this was causing any issues, but the result is the same. I've also checked the username, password and Cloud SQL instance name, they are all correct.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you open the port 3307 in the GCP Firewall? By default it comes blocked.

Comment: @gabidavila No I haven't, how would I do this?

Comment: You could connect to the default port on the database, which is 3306, instead of going to trouble to open that port, is that possible for you? Also remember that when running the cloud_sql_proxy you need to put the instance connection name, not the IP address of the instance for connection.

Comment: Yes I did put the instance name - interestingly I am connecting to 3306 in my settings, so i'm not sure why the error shows 3307.